# Python pandas dataframe check if values of one column is in another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe:

```
id         attr
1          val1
2          val1||val2
3          val1||val3
4          val3
```

and a list `special_val = ['val1', 'val2', 'val4']`

I want to filter the first dataframe to keep rows whose ALL `attr` values are in the list. So I need the results to be like this:

```
id     attr
1      val1                #val1 is in special_val
2      val1||val2          #both val1 and val2 are in special_val
```

I am thinking of using `pandas.DataFrame.isin` or `pandas.Series.isin` but I can't come up with the correct syntax. Could you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine `str.split`, `isin()`, and `groupby()`:

```
s = df['attr'].str.split('\|+', expand=True).stack().isin(special_val).groupby(level=0).all()
df[s]
```

Output:

```
   id        attr
0   1        val1
1   2  val1||val2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following.

```
df['match'] = df['attr'].apply(lambda x: True if set(x.split('||')).intersection(set(special_val)) else False)
df[df['match'] == True]
```

**Output**

```
   id        attr
0   1        val1
1   2  val1||val2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```py
import numpy as np
special_val = set(['val1', 'val2', 'val4'])

df["attr2"]=df["attr"].str.split("\|\|").map(set)
df=df.loc[df["attr2"].eq(np.bitwise_and(df["attr2"], special_val))].drop(columns="attr2")
```

Outputs:

```py
   id        attr
0   1        val1
1   2  val1||val2
```